# matplotlib: How to get imshow colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've plotted an image using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)
```

image is a NxM numpy array with only 5 different values.
How can I get a list of the RGB values that these 5 values have been mapped to in the image shown with imshow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't know in advance what your values in your image are going to be, you can use `np.unique` to find all unique values, then use `norm` and `cmap` properties of the `AxesImage` returned by `imshow`

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imshow(image)
colours = im.cmap(im.norm(np.unique(image))
```

Comment: Ok, that's more concise. I accept your answer, although for my particular case I have to specify the values to norm as some times they don't appear in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a way do doing it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645476/python-matplotlib-get-pixel-value-after-colormap-applied) other question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
art = plt.imshow(image)
colours = [art.cmap(art.norm(c)) for c in range(1,6)]
```

colours contains the colours I needed.